# How to resize a partition in Vista with more choice?

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning

I have a partition D of about 170GB, with 90G of it free. Now I need a new partition of about 50GB.

I tried the built-in partition tool, but it says there's only about 20GB of space to shrink.

What is the problem?

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I have the same issue, and defragmenting did not solve anything because the end of the disk has unmoveable blocks. Answer for this case would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up your important data and then [install this free partitioning software](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) to make your partition.

Windows built in partitioning is very limited.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem could be that the partition is fragmented. There is not enough continuous free space to reduce the partition size more than 20GB. You're best chance is to defragment the hard drive multiple times and try again. Worst case, you can use a Linux LiveCD (Ubuntu) and try to use GParted to partition the drive.

Comment: +1 I would suggest, you first defragment the drive and then try to shrink it. This will mostly solve your issue.